# File encryption and decryption on Linux using ucrypt

Tags: linux, encryption

A few years back, I was using the `ucrypt` utility on CentOS 5. Now I am using Fedora 11 and need `ucrypt` for file encryption and decryption, but I don't have a backup of the old system. Where can I find `ucrypt` now?

Comment: I prefer you to go for either truecrypt or cryptsetup

Comment: I have some old files which were encrypted using ucrypt. I am not sure how to decrypt those files using truecrypt or cryptsetup. Can you please suggest on that too.

Comment: Please don't crosspost - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202449/file-encryption-and-decryption-on-linux-using-ucrypt

Comment: What is ucrypt? I never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are probably looking for is `cfs-utils`. A google search should find you some RPMs that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Try `yum` if it finds anything:

```
yum provides \*/ucrypt
```

I couldn't find anything, so I'd simply compile it myself. There is a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/tkunwar/ucrypt) providing `ucrypt`.